# What is the meaning of this (undefined getCameraForLocationToPoint) error and how to fix?

Tags: javascript, angular, bing-maps

This is error which I don't understand `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCameraForLocationToPoint')`

I got this error when I try to create a Bingmap for my angular project

**.TS**

```
    let loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(Latitude,Longitude);

    this.map.setView({ center: { latitude: loc.latitude, longitude: loc.longitude }});
    this.map.setView({ mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.streetside });
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.map, 'viewchangeend', () => { this.updateView(this.map); });
    this.updateView(this.map);

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.map, 'click', this.Clicked.bind(this.map));

    streetViewMapPromise(promise: Promise<any>) {

       promise.then(x => {

         this.map = x;
      })
   }

  Clicked(e){ //click event
    console.log(e)
  }
```

**.Html**

```
<app-rs-bingmap (MapPromise)="streetViewMapPromise($event)" [options]="_mapOptions"></app-rs-bingmap>
```

above section is my Bingmap v8 component import section. As well as my click event is not working too. when I click on the map I want to show and alert.

Here is the stackblitz : [getCameraForLocationToPoint error here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bing-maps-j5smri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fbing-api-loader.service.ts)

Comment: can you provide where does it throw the error?

Comment: I debug the code I get this error when excute the code this place : this.map.setView({ center: { latitude: loc.latitude, longitude: loc.longitude }});

Comment: some times this error came somtimes not

Comment: just assuming here but it might be coming from  loc.latitude. and if the error is not always there, it might have to do with the state of the map on your browser maybe? stackblitz code would be a lot helpful to debug this to be honest.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bing-maps-j5smri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fbing-api-loader.service.ts

Comment: see this has that error